# Matrix Report showing a row with Blank value

Tags: reporting, salesforce-id

I have matrix report where in I have only two rows, One with filter value 'Yes' and other is  '-', I am trying to filter the report only with 'Yes' value, but this is not working. Also when I select the row and drill down the report, I don see the change. I am viewing this report in console.

Is there any workaround for this problem. [image: See the image attached. I think this will give you better idea.]

Any help on this will be of Gr8 help..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I can;t quite make it out in the picture, but it doesn't look like you have a filter on the report specifying 'Your Field = 'Yes'

Answer (score 1):

In current picture

- Click on "Customise" button. This will open report in edit mode
- Now click on "Add" button which label named "Filters" and add required filter to it.

This snapshot may give some idea
[image: Add Filter]

Comment: Also did that.. It is not helping.. Another thing I noticed is when I drill down with '-' selected, it brings the table only to that particular row, the same don happen with row 'Yes' selected . What could be the reason ??

Comment: Row which are shown by '-' is grouping of 'null/empty' value. So reporting currently don't have any method of filtering these type of values. One workaround can be done is if you are filtering using picklist value the add filter for all possible values. @PhanirajNadiger

Comment: You can filter by null values: `Field name equals ` (no value in the value box), or `Field name not equal to ` (no value in the box). Do not use `-`, despite that being shown, because it's not a literal `-`... it's null.